# c# Linq or code to extract groups from a single list of source data

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, linq

I have data in a list coming from a 3rd party dll. I cant change how the data arrives. It is a list as this unbroken and contiguous with no separators

```
List<MyType> DataList
```

Each row has an index number associated. Index numbers can be from 1 to 4 max number 4. So in optimal we would see groups of lines numbered 1 to 4, one group after the other. But groups can be missing an index number.

As you can see here the first group has 1-4, the second group has 1,2,4 (missing 3) and the third group has 1,2,3 (missing 4), and also the rows can be inserted so the indexes are not in any order

The gaps in rows you see here i put in for clarity only

```
    Filename    Index   Time                
    File_1      1       42038.6924500000    
    File_2      2       42038.6435300000    
    File_3      3       42038.7962800000    
    File_4      4       42038.9340600000    

    File_5      2       42938.9561300000    
    File_6      1       42939.0110700000    
    File_7      4       42939.5551700000    

    File_8      2       43838.9652200000    
    File_9      1       43839.0111500000    
    File_10     3       43839.0990100000
```

I need to extract from this list into 4 separate groups, based on the index number. So each group is made up from either all index 1 or all index 2 etc.
but where an index number is missing i need to insert a spacer fill row to indicated a missing index.

EG the above should end up like

```
group on index 1
File_1      1       42038.6924500000    
File_6      1       42939.0110700000  
File_9      1       43839.0111500000    

group 2 on index 2
File_2      2       42038.6435300000    
File_5      2       42938.9561300000 
File_8      2       43838.9652200000    

group 3 on index 3
File_3      3       42038.7962800000    
File_spacer 3       00000.0000000000
File_10     3       43839.0990100000   

group 4 on index 4
File_4      4       42038.9340600000
File_7      4       42939.5551700000 
File_spacer 4       00000.0000000000
```

So i could do Linq

```
DataList.GroupBy(x => X.Index)).ToList()
```

but this wont insert the File_spacer  Index  0000.000000000 entry i need in there to replace the missing index as a placeholder.

The list typically can contain 500 rows of data in this fashion but i cant come up with c# code to extract and format as i need.

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: After you group, loop through each group and see if the count in the group is lower than number x and add a spacer.

Comment: Since it seems the indexes may appear in any position, how did you decide that, in group 3, the index 3 substitute will occupy the 2nd position, while in group 4 it will end up in the last position?

Comment: @jimi because its a missing index 3 from the second "grouping" of numbers (as represented by me with a spacing for clarity). the 3rd grouping is missing index 4 therefore the spacer for index number 4 goes in the third position. the idea with the spacing is to keep positional parity from group to group.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
double tickPerDay = (double)(24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 10000000.0);
List<MyType> DataList = new List<MyType>() {
    new MyType() { Filename = "File_1", Index = 1, Time = (DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900").AddDays(42038)).AddTicks((long)(tickPerDay * .6924500000))},
    new MyType() { Filename = "File_2", Index = 2, Time = (DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900").AddDays(42038)).AddTicks((long)(tickPerDay * .6435300000))},
    new MyType() { Filename = "File_3", Index = 3, Time = (DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900").AddDays(42038)).AddTicks((long)(tickPerDay * .7962800000))},
    new MyType() { Filename = "File_4", Index = 4, Time = (DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900").AddDays(42038)).AddTicks((long)(tickPerDay * .9340600000))},
    new MyType() { Filename = "File_5", Index = 2, Time = (DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900").AddDays(42038)).AddTicks((long)(tickPerDay * .9561300000))},
    new MyType() { Filename = "File_6", Index = 1, Time = (DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900").AddDays(42039)).AddTicks((long)(tickPerDay * .9561300000))},
    new MyType() { Filename = "File_7", Index = 4, Time = (DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900").AddDays(42039)).AddTicks((long)(tickPerDay * .5551700000))},
    new MyType() { Filename = "File_8", Index = 2, Time = (DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900").AddDays(42038)).AddTicks((long)(tickPerDay * .9652200000))},
    new MyType() { Filename = "File_9", Index = 1, Time = (DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900").AddDays(42039)).AddTicks((long)(tickPerDay * .0111500000))},
    new MyType() { Filename = "File_10", Index = 3, Time = (DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900").AddDays(42039)).AddTicks((long)(tickPerDay * .0990100000))}
    };

int maxIndex = DataList.Max(x => x.Index);

var results = DataList.GroupBy(x => x.Index)
    .Select(x => Enumerable.Range(1, maxIndex)
        .Select(y => x.Any(z => z.Index == y) ? x.Where(z => z.Index == y).FirstOrDefault() : new MyType() { Filename = "File_spacer", Index = y, Time = DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900")})
        .ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: [`System.TimeSpan.TicksPerDay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.ticksperday).